# Excel - Multiple Conditions with 2 variables

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am working on a excel data set whereby I have two variables -

1) One time Spend

2) Installment Spend.

Now, the observations under these two variables contain 4 possibilities.

A - One time Spend>0,Installment Spend=0

B - One time Spend=0,Installment Spend>0

C - One time Spend=0,Installment Spend=0

D - One time Spend>0,Installment Spend>0.

I want to create a new variable called Spend type which can classify the Spend based on

A-Onetime Spend,

B-Installment Spend,

C-No Spend,

D-Both One time and Installment.

Can anybody help me with creating this new variable in excel?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZONhL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like a formula? I have added an invalid category in case of empty cells.

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A2),ISBLANK(B2)),"invalid",IF(AND(A2=0,B2=0),"No spend",IF(AND(A2>0,B2>0),"Both",IF(AND(A2=0,B2>0),"Installment spend","One time spend"))))
```

[image: Spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different formula approach:

```
=INDEX({"No Spend","Onetime Spend","Installment Spend","Both One time and Installment"},MATCH((A2>0)+(B2>0)*2,{0,1,2,3},0))
```

[image]

---

Or this shorter version:

```
=CHOOSE((A2>0)+(B2>0)*2+1,"No Spend","Onetime Spend","Installment Spend","Both One time and Installment")
```

[image]